# Creating a remote database connection using Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to create a remote database connection using Java. I have read many Microsoft and internet articles on how to set it up. I am getting close but I keep running into errors. I imported the sqljdbc.jar and I pointed it to the sqljdbc_auth.dll 64 bit. (I am running 64 bit locally).

I am coming up with the error below. I checked different sites about this error and it said to create a new workspace and I did. But I am still getting the same error. Please help me!!!!

Thank you!

Java code

```
try { 
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url =    "jdbc:sqlserver://chaitsqlcs03:1433;DatabaseName=IDMR12_tiaa;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"********","*********");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
  conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

error in the console in eclispe:

```
>
```

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007032dd27, pid=10204, tid=9544
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x5dd27]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   C:\Users\olsonjo\workspace\EndDate30Days\hs_err_pid10204.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: I would use another approach like creating a project closer to that server that consumes the data from the database and exposes it through services like RESTful services.

Comment: Is there a way to complete it the route I am going?

Comment: Have you put sqljdbc_auth.dll in your classpath?